# Delete the second dash in the rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have rows with numbers in it. The numbers look like: `A-123456`, `A-123456-P`, `A-387785`, `F-489186`, `T-826926-P-2`.

So I need for all numbers with `-P` or `-P-2` at the end to remove it, so only the first half remained: `A-123456-P` ---> `A-123456`, `T-826926-P-2` ---> `T-826926`.

I tried to do that by first finding and replacing all `P*`. But it left me with `-` at the end of each such number remaining. I guess I can't just find `*-` and replace it with nothing, because it would leave me with `A` because of the first dash.  How would I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious from your examples that all valid values have a length of **8** characters.  So to remove the unwanted data at the right, use:

```
=LEFT(A1,8)
```

and copy down.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a whole spreadsheet with those, you may do the following:

```
Option Explicit

Function l_find_position(sInputString As String, sFindWhat As String, l_position As Long) As Long

    Dim l_counter As Long

    Application.Volatile
    l_find_position = 0

    For l_counter = 1 To l_position
        l_find_position = InStr(l_find_position + 1, sInputString, sFindWhat)
        If l_find_position = 0 Then Exit For
    Next

End Function

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim my_cell     As Range

    For Each my_cell In Selection
        On Error Resume Next
        my_cell = Left(my_cell, l_find_position(my_cell.Text, "-", 2) - 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next my_cell

End Sub
```

Pretty much, the function `l_find_position` locates the position of the n-th sign and this one is given as a parameter to the Left() function. To see it working, simply `select`the range with the values you want to cut and run `TestMe`.

Have a nice Saturday! :)

Answer (score 1):

assuming the length of text until 2nd '-' is not always 8 characters then use the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(8),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",CHAR(8),2))-1)
```

since it can be done with formula, in vba just use

```
with application.worksheetfunctions
    result = .left(rng, .find(chr(8), .substitute(rng, "-", chr(8), 2) - 1)
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets `rng` be range where you have this values:

```
On Error GoTo Next
For Each r in rng.Cells
    If Right(r.Value, 2) = "-P" Then
        r.Value = Mid(r.Value, 0, Len(r.Value) - 2)
    End If
    If Right(r.Value, 4) = "-P-2" Then
        r.Value = Mid(r.Value, 0, Len(r.Value) - 4)
    End If
Next r
On Error GoTo 0
```